# Learning to use AXE library for ASP

Tags: json, asp-classic

I'm attempting to use the AXE library to parse some JSON data. In trying to make sure that everything is running correctly I have created a test page. I am getting an error:

Error Type:
Microsoft JScript compilation (0x800A03EA)
Syntax error
json2.asp Line 1

I'm using the code that is in the json2.asp file to test this out:

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server" src="json2.asp"></script>
<%

dim TestData : set TestData = JSON.parse(join(array( _
    "{", _
    "  ""firstname"": ""Fabio"",", _
    "  ""lastname"": ""Nagao"",", _
    "  ""alive"": true,", _
    "  ""age"": 27,", _
    "  ""nickname"": ""nagaozen"",", _
    "  ""fruits"": [", _
    "    ""banana"",", _
    "    ""orange"",", _
    "    ""apple"",", _
    "    ""papaya"",", _
    "    ""pineapple""", _
    "  ],", _
    "  ""complex"": {", _
    "    ""real"": 1,", _
    "    ""imaginary"": 2", _
    "  }", _
    "}" _
)))

Response.write(TestData.firstname & vbNewline) ' prints Fabio
Response.write(TestData.alive & vbNewline) ' prints True
Response.write(TestData.age & vbNewline) ' prints 27
Response.write(TestData.fruits.get(0) & vbNewline) ' prints banana
Response.write(TestData.fruits.get(1) & vbNewline) ' prints orange
Response.write(TestData.complex.real & vbNewline) ' prints 1
Response.write(TestData.complex.imaginary & vbNewline) ' prints 2

' You can also enumerate object properties ...

dim key : for each key in TestData.keys()
    Response.write( key & vbNewline )
next

set TestData = nothing
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What's on line 1 of `json2.asp`?

Comment: <script language="Javascript">

Comment: You don't need `<script></script>` tags in that file, just the javascript code

Comment: Even though it is an asp file?

Comment: Have you looked at some of the other [related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Basp-classic%5D+axe+json)?

Comment: Yeah I have looked at most of those questions. Those other questions were where I got the idea of using ASP to parse JSON. I've been working with it little bit and now that the following error:Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A01A8)
Object required: '' which points to this line: set TestData = JSON.parse(join(array( _